# Embedding foreign keys in Rails Active Model Serializer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, active-model-serializers

I know that when embedding associations we can do the following

```
has_many :task_observer, embed: :objects


has_many :task_observer, embed: :ids
```

Is there a way to to embed a different field in the association other than the id, like contact_id or task_name as the array instead of the primary key? Please let me know.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure of what you want, but how thing I like to do is to write a serializer for the related object. In your case, that would be a serializer for the TaskObserver model. Then the has_many would use this serializer to serialize all the models. That gives you a full control of which fields you want to serialize. But I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for.

Comment: the embed: :ids gives me an array of task_observer ids like this
task_observers: [
22,
20,
18
]
If I add a serializer for TaskObserver model and restrict attributes, I get something like this:
task_observers: [
{
contact_id: 22
},
{
contact_id: 20
},
{
contact_id: 18
}
]

Comment: and that doesn't suit you ? I mean it seems to me that it's a good idea to have Hashes here so you know what kind of ids you're working with. Cause if you just have simple list, then it kinda lose its original purpose. No ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What if you would do something like :

```
attributes :task_observer_contact_ids

def task_observer_contact_ids
  object.task_observers.map(&:contact_id)
end
```

Is it what you're looking for ?

Answer (score 0):

embed_key is even better

```
has_many :task_observer, embed: :ids, embed_key: :custom_id_field_name
```